# how to take input of two string?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char a[1001];
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    while(t--)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(a);
        printf("%d\t",t);
        puts(a);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2 
die another day.
i'm batman.
```

Ouput:

```
1   
0   die another day.
```

Expected Output:

```
1    die another day.
0    i'm batman.
```

Anyone please help how to accept more than one string without any bugs.
I am able to see after entering 2 my gets is taking newline as first string and later second string properly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Technically `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. It's not supported on all systems and platforms.

Comment: Any idea to make the program work on almost compilers properly?Including online compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `scanf()` of `stdin` to read input. Never call `fflush(stdin);` either, but if you stop using `scanf()` you will no longer want to.

Read whole lines using [`fgets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) into suitably-sized string buffers, then parse what you got. One good function for parsing a string is [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) which is just like `scanf()` except it reads from a string instead.

This will be much easier, less annoying, and just generally better. Oh, and of course *never* use `gets()`.

Something like this (untested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char line[256];

  if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
  {
    int count;
    if(sscanf(line, "%d", &count) == 1)
    {
      while(count > 0)
      {
        if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
        {
          printf("%s", line);
          --count;
        }
        else
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I m a  newbie can you please give a example how to use fgets()

Comment: Can you explain the flow i am not able to get the functionality of the methods mention

Comment: @tech_boy I made `fgets()` and `sscanf()` into links, so you can read the documentation to figure out exactly how those functions work.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use fflush(stdin). use `getchar()` to clear the [enter] character left after `scanf()` as,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char a[1001];
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
     getchar();
    while(t--)
    {

        gets(a);
        printf("%d\t",t);
        puts(a);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

it works.