# unable to take two input strings in C on Ubuntu

Tags: c

I am unable to take two inputs strings simultaneously in C on Ubuntu. It shows the wrong output.
Simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char s1[20],char s2[20],printf("\nEnter job:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",s1);
    printf("Enter hobby:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",s2);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter job:student
Enter hobby:
student
```

It does not allow the input of a second string. How can I overcome this bug?

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",s1);` --> `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s1);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to take input of two string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135602/how-to-take-input-of-two-string)

Comment: Note that the code won't compile, even when formatted correctly.  You need a semi-colon before the first `printf()`, not a comma.  The problem is that there's a newline in the input and your format won't allow the the newline to be read, so it fails.  Check the return status of `scanf()`.  And read the newline before scanning, or put a space before the `%[^\n]`.  Also notice that a scan set is `%[…]`; it is not a modifier for `%s`.

Comment: `scanf` should be given the maximum number of characters to read and store into `s1` and `s2`, otherwise invalid input will invoke undefined behavior.  This kind of bug is a blatant security flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow embedded spaces, modify the `scanf` formats this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char job[100], hobby[100];
    printf("Enter job:");
    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", job);
    printf("Enter hobby:");
    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", hobby);
    printf("%s,%s", job, hobby);
    return 0;
}
```

But be aware that empty lines will not be accepted by this `scanf` format. The linefeed will stay in the input stream, the second `scanf` will fail too and `job` and/or `hobby` will have indeterminate contents, letting `printf` invoke undefined behavior.

Is is much more reliable to use `fgets()` and strip the `'\n'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char job[100], hobby[100];

    printf("Enter job:");
    if (!fgets(job, sizeof job, stdin))
        return 1;
    job[strcspn(job, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("Enter hobby:");
    if (!fgets(hobby, sizeof hobby, stdin))
        return 1;
    hobby[strcspn(hobby, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("%s,%s", job, hobby);
    return 0;
}
```